# How to wrapper multiple classes in different files into a single function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0, rollupjs

I am facing an issue with typescript build while trying to wrapper multiple classes into a single function.

Below is the sample code.

```
// AppState.ts
export class AppState {
    static id: string;
}


// AppLogic.ts
import { AppState } from './AppState'
export class AppLogic{
    
    constructor(id : string){
        AppState.id = id;        
    }

    public getAppID() : string{
        return AppState.id;
    }
}

// main.ts
import { AppLogic } from './AppLogic';
export function AppwrapAPI(id : string): any{
    
    class AppAPI{        
        private app : AppLogic;

        constructor(id : string){
            this.app = new AppLogic(id);        
        }

        public getAppID() : string{
            return this.app.getAppID();

        }
    }
    return new AppAPI(id);
}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test app</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="module">
      
      import  { AppwrapAPI }  from "./dist/main.es.js";


      let a1 =  new AppwrapAPI("123");
      alert(a1.getAppID());                    ///"123"

      let a2 = new AppwrapAPI("321");          ///"321"
      alert(a2.getAppID());

      alert(a1.getAppID());                    ///"321"  <<--- wrong data


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above ts project generates the following js code using rollup built.

```
var AppState = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AppState() {
    }
    return AppState;
}());var AppLogic = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AppLogic(id) {
        AppState.id = id;
    }
    AppLogic.prototype.getAppID = function () {
        return AppState.id;
    };
    return AppLogic;
}());function AppwrapAPI(id) {
    var AppAPI = /** @class */ (function () {
        function AppAPI(id) {
            this.app = new AppLogic(id);
        }
        AppAPI.prototype.getAppID = function () {
            return this.app.getAppID();
        };
        return AppAPI;
    }());
    return new AppAPI(id);
}export{AppwrapAPI};//# sourceMappingURL=main.es.js.map
```

In this code, the AppwrapAPI function wraps only the AppAPI function instead of all the functions and the AppState function is outside the AppwrapAPI function which creates an issue when I create multiple instances for the AppwrapAPI function.

```
let a1 =  new AppwrapAPI("123");
alert(a1.getAppID());                    ///"123"

let a2 = new AppwrapAPI("321");          ///"321"
alert(a2.getAppID());

alert(a1.getAppID());                    ///"321"  <<--- wrong data
```

I want to wrapper all the three classes AppState, AppLogic, AppAPI inside the AppwrapAPI function so that the AppState is not shared between the multiple instances.
Similar to the below code

```
"use strict";
function AppwrapAPI(id) {
    class AppState {
    }
    class AppLogic {
        constructor(id) {
            AppState.id = id;
        }
        getAppID() {
            return AppState.id;
        }
    }
    class AppAPI {
        constructor(id) {
            this.app = new AppLogic(id);
        }
        getAppID() {
            return this.app.getAppID();
        }
    }
    return new AppAPI(id);
}
let a1 = AppwrapAPI("123");
console.log(a1.getAppID()); /// output : 123
let a2 = AppwrapAPI("321");
console.log(a2.getAppID()); /// output : 321
console.log(a1.getAppID()); /// output : 123
```

Right now I manually modifying the generated code to avoid this issue but it gives me some other issue while debugging with the source map generated from the old file.

Can anyone suggest to me how to modify the typescript code to get the single function that wraps all the classes in the typescript project?

Comment: Given your code `AppState` is simply a global container for a static id variable. Naturally a change to it will be reflected. Is there any good reason to have this being `static`?

Comment: @Yoshi thanks for the reply. This is a sample code of my project to illustrate the use case. Actually, in my project, AppState contains more than 20 objects which are used in different TS class files.AppState acts as a global store for specific instances. I will build this project and use it in another project where I want to create multiple instances for this project. I am facing an issue when I create multiple instances.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but I don't understand why then you would use a static property. Which, by it's very definition, is [shared across all instances](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties). So, if you want instances, create them accordingly (e.g. `new AppState(...)`) and make it's properties private to the instance.